# convert all factor columns to character in a data.frame without affecting non-factor columns

Tags: r, dataframe

For example I have a data.frame with both integer column and factor columns.

```
data <- data.frame(
    a = 1:5, 
    b = factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")), 
    c = factor(c("f", "g", "h", "i", "j")))`
```

And I want to convert b and c factor columns into character, with keeping column a as integer.

I tried the follwing code :

`sapply(data, function(x) {if_else(is.factor(x), as.character(x), x)})`

Instead of getting the result, it throws an error:

> Error: `true` must be length 1 (length of `condition`), not 5

I knew this can be done by mutate_if function in dplyr. But I still wonder why my code does not work for this case.

Thank you very much for any suggestions!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- data.frame(a = 1:5, 
                b = factor(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e")), 
                c = factor(c("f", "g", "h", "i", "j")))
d %>% glimpse() 
Observations: 5
Variables: 3
$ a <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
$ b <fctr> a, b, c, d, e
$ c <fctr> f, g, h, i, j

d %>% 
  mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>% 
  glimpse()
Observations: 5
Variables: 3
$ a <int> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
$ b <chr> "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"
$ c <chr> "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"
```

Using base R you can try

```
d[] <- lapply(d, function(x) if(is.factor(x)) as.character(x) else x)
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who would like to use base R and preserve the data frame structure, rather than the list from `lapply`:

```
factor_to_characters = function(x)
{
    factor_cols = sapply(x, is.factor)
    x[factor_cols] = lapply(x[factor_cols], as.character)
    x   
}
```

Test it out:

```
> class(iris[, "Species"])
[1] "factor"
> 
> i2 = factor_to_character(iris)
> class(i2[, "Species"])
[1] "character"
```

Answer (score 0):

The `mutate_if` is deprecated in favor of using [the `tidy-select` framework](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/select.html), i.e.,

```r
library(tidyverse)

iris %>% 
  mutate(across(where(is.factor), as.character)) %>% 
  glimpse

## Rows: 150
## Columns: 5
## $ Sepal.Length <dbl> 5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0, 5.4, 4.6, 5.0, 4.4, 4.9, 5.4, 4.8, 4.8, 4.3, 5.8, 5.7, 5.4, …
## $ Sepal.Width  <dbl> 3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6, 3.9, 3.4, 3.4, 2.9, 3.1, 3.7, 3.4, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 4.4, 3.9, …
## $ Petal.Length <dbl> 1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4, 1.7, 1.4, 1.5, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.6, 1.4, 1.1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.3, …
## $ Petal.Width  <dbl> 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, …
## $ Species      <chr> "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "seto…
```